# nginx points the sub-directory of an alias folder to the base directory

Tags: nginx, directory

I am new to Nginx. Now I have a confusion on nginx configurations:

My web site contains folders in different locations:

```
location / {
  root /Path1;
}

location ^~ /download {
  alias /Path2;
}
```

When I query `http://mysite/download`, I am accessing the content of `/Path2` instead of `/Path1`

Now I want to add a sub-directory under `download` containing my private files, and I want to add password protection. So I add:

```
location /download/personal {
  auth_basic "Admin Login";
  auth_basic_user_file Path_to_htpasswd;
}
```

But I got 404 error when querying `http://mysite/download/personal` after key in my credentials. According to nginx error log, I am directed to `/Path1/download/personal`, which does not exist. How can I configure nginx, such that all access to `http://mysite/download/*` will be directed to the same directory in `/Path2`?

**Update:**

I may find a solution: just put the sub-directory configuration in the parent conf:

```
location ^~ /download {
  alias /Path2;
  location /download/personal {
    auth_basic "Admin Login";
    auth_basic_user_file Path_to_htpasswd;
  }
}
```

Is it correct? Or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to do this. You need to add an `alias` that points to the correct directory.

Comment: Yes. That is a solution. But then for every subfolder I created I have to make the changes. Is there any solution to configure `http://mysite/personal/*` all point to /Path2?

Comment: Why do you need to create so many `location`s? You should more clearly explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have modified my post :)  I just want to create a public accessible folder, in which there exists an encrypted subfolder.